# I have tried linking my CSS to my HTML but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html

I am trying to learn HTML and CSS. I have tried using my CSS but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="styling.css">
<script src="../(public)/js/js.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>MyPortfolio</title>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background : (red);
}
```

Comment: You should not have parentheses around the value `red`.

Comment: removed them and it still dosent work

Comment: Right, didn't say it would work. That's why it's a comment, not an answer. And the word is spelled "doesn't".

Comment: Clear your cache, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styling.css">
```

The folder directory of your CSS file determines how you link it. 
Its best practice to link your script at the end of your web page, before the end of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its not "src", its "href".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

I suggest you put that script tag on the bottom of your page.

Oh and one last thing, that css is incorrect. Here's what you should use:

```
body{
    background:red; /* Or #ff0000 */
}
```

Comment: it dosent seem to be working. I have the css in the same folder as my index. i have tried using html <style> and that works so I can only imagine it being the link it self

Comment: @DawidStarzec when directly accessing the "styling.css" file, do you get any errors? Replacing `src` by `href` should solve the issue for you.